# node.js azure storage blob

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am Azure&node.js beginner. I tried to exec file upload sample below on node.js, but it does not work at `blob.client.createContainerIfNotExists()`.

Error displays:

```
Error: createContainerIfNotExists
```

It means that error case of `createContainerIfNotExists()` displays simply.

I wonder if I mistake how to write `blob.client.createContainerIfNotExists()` or, `azure.createBlobService()` could not success.

```
node.js version v0.6.12
express version 2.5.11
azure version 0.5.3
```

Thank you!

```
/**********************/
  File upload sample:
/**********************/

var DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT = 'xxxxx';
var DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY= 'xxxx';
var DEVSTORE_BLOB_HOST = 'xxxxx';

var express = require('express')
, routes = require('./routes');

var util   = require('util');

// Azure module
var azure  = require('azure');
var blob   = require('./blob.js');


// BLOB container
blob.CONTAINER = 'nodejs';

// BLOB service
 blob.client = azure.createBlobService(
  DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT,
  DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY,
  DEVSTORE_BLOB_HOST);

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

 // Configuration

app.configure(function() {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  // app.use(express.logger());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes

app.get('/', routes.index);

// BLOB upload
app.get('/upload', routes.upload);

// BLOB upload
app.post('/uploadtoblob', routes.uploadblob);

// BLOB list
app.get('/list', routes.listblobs);

// BLOB delete
app.post('/delete/:id', routes.deleteblob);

// BLOB property
app.get('/info/:id', routes.information);

// BLOB container create
blob.client.createContainerIfNotExists(blob.CONTAINER, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error : createContainerIfNotExists');
    process.exit(1);
  } else {

    blob.client.setContainerAcl(blob.CONTAINER,         azure.Constants.BlobConstants.BlobContainerPublicAccessType.BLOB, function(err) {
      if(err) {
    console.log('Error : setContainerAcl');
    process.exit(1);
      }
    });
  }
});

var port = process.env.port || 3000;
app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port,     app.settings.env);
});
```

Comment: It may be worthwhile tracking the request/response via a tool like Fiddler or logging the details of actual error. That would tell you exactly why your request failed. It could fail for any number of reasons - invalid blob container name, invalid credentials etc.

Comment: you cna also try printing more data in console.log (for example, oiutputting the actual error you get).  This could simply be bad credentials, but it would be impossible to debug without more informationa bout the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest azure sdk for node  requires node version > 0.6.l5. I would suggest upgrading both the sdk and your node version.

You can change your code as follows to get more information on the specific error:

console.log('Error : createContainerIfNotExists' + JSON.stringify(err));

You need to eitehr have the azure storage emulator runnign locally *or* you need to provide credentials for an azure storage account that the app can use.  The is usually done through the AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT and AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY environment variables, or by passing in a connection string to the createBlobService factory.

For step-by-step samples on setting up your first application using blob storage, see:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/how-to-guides/blob-storage/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the problem was totally node version old.